# Can't get my conditional to check input value for str or int and ignore if statement (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, string, if-statement, integer

Trying to write a simple if, elif statement. I prompt the user for an input and:
if input is an int(), run the if seconds => statement and begin countdown.
elif input is a str(), print to the user to input an int().

```
print("We're ready captain! How many seconds until launch?")

seconds = input()

isInputString = type(seconds) == str #yields True if seconds == str()

if isInputString == True: #tell the user to try again
    print("I need a number Captain!")
    seconds = input() #prompt a second input

else: #else it wasn't a str() and to proceed on with script
    pass
```

Currently the script will prompt for a second input even if a int() was entered.

Is this due to how I entered my if - else statement?

I feel like it should resort to else - pass if an int() is entered but it still prompts the 2nd branch input() even though isInputString == False.

Comment: The value returned by input is *always* a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the type to `int` inside a `try..except` or use the `.isdigit()` method. Better way:

```
print("We're ready captain! How many seconds until launch?")
while True:
    try:
        seconds = int(input())
    except:
        print("I need a number Captain!")
    else:
        break

print(seconds)
```